# Close an Access form and use next form in stack

Tags: vba, database, ms-access-2016

I have a family history database. I occasionally need to add a father or mother to a record "on the fly". I do  not want to close the database, add a record, then open it again. Accordingly, I added a button btnQuickAdd which opens a small form (frmQuickAdd) to add in the father/mother's name, date of birth, and gender. The frmQuickAdd has a "Save" button which closes the frmQuickAdd and then requeries the main form using code
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmQuickAdd", acSaveYes
Me.Requery
However, using me.requery just results in error 2467 - the object is not open or does not exist. The main form clearly is still open. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Do not use reference `Me.`  on closing form but absolute reference to main form: `Forms("mainform").Requery`.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you are trying the requery the `frmQuickAdd`.

I presume your `frmQuickAdd` is loaded through a button on the main form. If that's the case, then the `.Requery` needs to happen on the next line where the form is loaded.

```
Private Sub btnQuickAdd_Click()
    
    'open form
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmQuickAdd", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acDialog
    
    'requery
    Me.Requery
    
End Sub
```

Also, you can avoid the hard-coded form name when closing by using the form's `Name` property:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveYes
```

**Edit**

The above snippet will always requery the main form when the edit-form is loaded. If this behavior is not wanted, you can requery the main form when the save button is clicked using the form's name.

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveYes
Forms.MainForm.Requery
```

Note, `MainForm` must be loaded or you'll get an error.

Comment: Add `DataMode = acDialog` so the Requery will wait until the popup is closed.

Comment: @Andre Indeed. Thanks for pointing it out.